# textarea maxlength dropdown menu

Tags: jquery, textarea, maxlength, dropdown

I have a dropdown menu with 3 values and depending on what value you select in the menu I want the textarea MaxLength to change. Is this possible or can it work?

I have looked at jQuery val() and change() but not got it to work.

/best regards

Comment: Please share your html structure and show what you tried.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **[`change()`](https://api.jquery.com/change/)** for listening change event and **[`attr()`](https://api.jquery.com/attr/)** for setting `maxlength` attribute

**Update :** use **[`val()`](https://api.jquery.com/val/)** for updating if content length is greater than maxlength while changing dropdown value

```js
$('#len').change(function() {
  var len = this.value;
  $('#text').attr('maxlength', len).val(function(i, v) {
    return v.length > len? v.substring(0, len): v;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id=len>
  <option value=10>10</option>
  <option value=20>20</option>
  <option value=30>30</option>
  <option value=40>40</option>
</select>

<textarea maxlength=10 id=text></textarea>
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to set the `maxlength` attribute of your `textarea` to change its length based on the value selected from dropdown.

**HTML Code:**

```
<textarea id="txtarea" maxlength="5"></textarea>
<select id="dropdown">
  <option value="5">Five</option>
  <option value="50">Fifty</option>
  <option value="100">Hundread</option>
</select>
```

**JS CODE:**

```
$(function () {
  $('#dropdown').on('change', function () {
     $('#txtarea').attr('maxlength', $(this).val());
  });
});
```

[Live Demo@ JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dreamweiver/qs6v4b9z/1/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like

```
<input id="myInput" type="text" maxlength="2">
 <select>
  <option onclick='changeMaxLength(2)'>2</option>
  <option onclick='changeMaxLength(5)'>5</option>
  <option onclick='changeMaxLength(10)'>10</option>
</select>
```

and jQuery

```
function changeMaxLength(length) {
    jQuery("#myInput").attr('maxlength', length);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's easy to do, you need to change the `maxlength` attribute of the textarea when the `select` changes.

The only issue is if the user click 'large' first and then goes back to 'small'. You'll need to cut the string to the small value length.

**HTML**

```
<select id="text-size">
   <option value="10">small</option>
   <option value="20">medium</option>
   <option value="40">large</option>
</select>
<textarea id="textarea" maxlength="10"></textarea>
```

**jQuery**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#text-size').on('change', function(event) {
       event.preventDefault();
       $textarea = $('#textarea');
       size = $(this).val();

       $textarea.attr('maxlength', size);
       $textarea.val($textarea.val().substr(0, size));
    });
});
```

Here is a demo http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EVyXGv

Comment: Post your code solution in answer itself and use demo just for testing. Answers should stand alone and make it easy to review without going off site. While you might have a great solution, the answer itself is very low quality when all it contains is a link

Answer (score 0):

Here is a java-script solution without jquery.
It finds the option you selected and sets a value to the text-area thereafter.

```js
var e = document.getElementById("list");

e.addEventListener("change", function() {
  var select = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
  var k = document.getElementById("area");
  k.innerHTML = "" + select;
  if (select == "first") {
    k.setAttribute("maxLength", 30);
  } else if (select == "second") {
    k.setAttribute("maxlength", 10);
    k.text = select;

  }
});
```

```html
<select id="list">
  <option>first</option>
  <option>second</option>
  <option>third</option>
  <option>fourth</option>
</select>

<textarea id="area">
  test
</textarea>
```